# Do curses have any impact or effect on Christians?

Tags: christian-living, curses

Christians believe that Jesus saved us by His blood. Since God is the only true God and through Jesus we have victory over Satan, it is claimed that we do not have to fear on curses.

But I hear many others says and even written books saying curses have effect on our lives and we need to deal with it. Is that correct in the New Testament era?

**I am looking for answers based on biblical references.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many kinds of curses, and Christians are certainly affected by some.

The first curse against any humans is found in [Genesis 3:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%203:17&version=NIV):

> To Adam he said, “Because you listened to your wife and ate fruit from the tree about which I commanded you, ‘You must not eat from it,’
>
> “Cursed is the ground because of you; 
>      through painful toil you will eat food from it 
>      all the days of your life.

Clearly all humans, including Christians, live under this curse.

Another type of curse is the so-called "Generational Curse:"

> Our ancestors sinned and are no more, 
>      and we bear their punishment. [Lamentations 5:7 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lamentations%205:7&version=NIV)

I think it's clear that this affects Christians, too.  Not only in the way scripture talks about these generational curses, but in every-day life.  Drug-addicted parents tend to have children with drug addictions--or other related social problems.  And the cycle is *very* hard to break!

I think the question you're really getting at is, are curses "cast" by one person on another, effectual against Christians.

[Proverbs 26:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2026:2&version=NIV) says:

> Like a fluttering sparrow or a darting swallow, 
>      an undeserved curse does not come to rest.

Proverbs is not always considered to be "hard and fast truths," though, and more "words to live by," so this may not mean that "undeserved curses" are never effectual. It's also unclear (at least to me) what *type* of curse this is actually referring to.

[This article](http://www.net-burst.net/bible/curse.htm) contends that Christians *can* be affected by curses (or other demonic/occult practices, such as fortune telling), especially when they open themselves up to such influences.  But that through Christ, we can always overcome these attacks and negative influences.

As a personal side note, for which I have no references yet (I'll try to add some later):

Most Christians believe in spiritual warfare in one form or another.  If spiritual warfare is a reality, then surely calling upon demons to harm Christians would be an act of spiritual warfare.  And while I believe Christ can always overcome these attacks, I don't believe that always means Christians will never experience the effects of these attacks.

Comment: Great Flimzy. I agree on Genesis quote. But how we can say that 'generational curse' and 'undeserved curse' still affects Christians once they are saved by Jesus by His death. That's why I am looking to link it with new testament, since we are no longer under the law and its effects. for eg: I do not believe we are cursed if we eat pork meat

Comment: @Jamess: Ahh, another class of curse, which I failed to address... let me think on that one.

Comment: You might want to add curses by God onto his holy people ([Leviticus 26:14-39](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2026:14-39&version=NIV) is a great example of this.)

Answer (score 2):

No, Satan cannot touch a true believer.

> **[I John 5:18 KJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%205:18&version=KJV)** We know that whosoever is born of God sinneth not; but he
>   that is begotten of God keepeth himself, and *that wicked one toucheth
>   him not.*

Jesus said that the Holy Ghost in us is greater than the one that is in the world.

> **[I John 4:4 KJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%204:4&version=KJV)** Ye are of God, little children, and have overcome them:
>   because greater is he that is in you, than he that is in the world.

Even if God were to 'curse us' Himself (Genesis 3:17, etc.), we have the promise that it would be for our good.

> **[Romans 8:28 KJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%208:28&version=KJV)** And we know that all things work together for good to them
>   that love God, to them who are the called according to his purpose.

Answer (score 0):

its very sad to me to see how much we ignore the supremacy of Christ.

1.-

Colossians 1:13 For he has rescued us from the dominion of darkness AND BROUGHT US (change of position) into the kingdom of the Son he loves.

2.- HAVING CANCELED the charge of our legal indebtedness which stood against us and condemned us, HE HAS TAKEN IT AWAY nailing it to the cross, AND HAVING DISARMED THE POWERS AND AUTHORITIES (pay attention its taking about ALL the demons) He made a public spectacle of them, triumphing over them by the cross.

3.-  Galatians 3:13 New Living Translation (NLT)

13 But Christ has rescued us from the curse pronounced by the law. When he was hung on the cross, he took upon himself the curse for our wrong doing. For it is written in the Scriptures, “Cursed is everyone who is hung on a tree.”[a]

Comment: I did not understand the conclusion. Let me re-word. Does  curses have effect on our lives who believes that we are saved the blood of Christ?